# Running NPM command shows empty output for www-data user

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm, permissions

Node v16.16.0 is installed by running the next terminal commands:

```
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash;
sudo apt install nodejs -y.
```

After installation, running a command:

```
sudo node -v
```

outputs:

```
v16.16.0
```

Running the same one as a www-data user:

```
sudo -u www-data node -v
```

outputs as the previous one as well:

```
v16.16.0
```

But the problem with `npm` command.
As long as the command runs within sudo
output has version

```
sudo npm -v
```

And the output is:

```
8.11.0
```

However, running as www-data outputs empty line.

```
sudo -u www-data npm -v
```

The same problem is for any npm command.

The question is why is this happening and how
to make npm commands work for www-data user.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your home folder for www-data is writable. You have to create folder `.npm` in it (and grant access for www-data).
In my case I had to do

```
mkdir /var/www/html/.npm/ && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/.npm/
```

I am not a skilled linux guy but I believe it could be also done more elegantly using `~/.npm`

Comment: Seems like the problem is with HOME environment variable. In my case, www-data user has no home directory

Comment: And for some reason npm tries to use /root directory which www-data has no permission